# How to prevent duplicate entry in SharkORM

Tags: ios, swift, database, sharkorm

I have implemented SharkORM in my Project.

Ref Site: https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm

I am searching for how to store a unique record in the table.

```
class tblFriend: SRKObject
{
    @objc dynamic var userId                : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var displayName           : String?
    @objc dynamic var userImage             : String?
}
```

I want to set **userId** as Primary key of the table or Any other way to stop duplication in the Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a new `userId` it needs to be unique in the model instead of `Int` that could possibly become duplicate. The best approach to avoid duplicate keys is to use `userId` as `String` with value `UUID().uuidString` like this:

```
@objc dynamic var userId = UUID().uuidString
```

If you have a requirement to only use `Int` for `userId` you could use `UUID`'s `hashValue` property too like this:

```
@objc dynamic var userId = UUID().hashValue
```